# Question about conditional probability identity

Tags: probability

I know that

$$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}$$

but is it also true that

$$P(A\mid B,C,D,E) = \frac{P(A,B,C,D,E)}{P(B) P(C) P(D) P(E)}$$

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No. The numerator is correct but the denominator is correct 
*only if* $$P(B\cap C\cap D\cap E) = P(B)P(C)P(D)P(E)$$
which equality *does not hold in general*. The equality *does*
hold when $B, C, D, E$ are independent events.

Comment: @user2041948 In other words, the denominator is only correct if B, C, D, and E are independent events.

Comment: @ZettaSuro  Ummm not quite. The stated equality can hold even if $B,C,D,E$ are _not_ independent events. It _always_ holds when they are independent events. Remember that for $B,C,D,E$ to be called independent events, we also need $P(B\cap C) = P(B)P(C)$, $P(B\cap D) = P(B)P(D)$, etc to hold, not just $P(B\cap C\cap D\cap E) = P(B)P(C)P(D)P(E)$.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense.  Much thanks!